# Jenkins: Groovy parse file - ansible inventory

Tags: groovy, ansible

I am currently trying to rebuild a Groovy script locally on my end so that it meets my requirements. I found the initial script here and it is supposed to extract all hostnames from an Ansible inventory. To implement the changes, I set up Visual Studio Code locally.
Unfortunately, I am not able to run the script. My code looks like this:

```
def getHostList(def appName, def filePath) {

    def hosts = []
    def content = readFile(file: filePath)
    def startCollect = false
    for(def line : content.split('\n')) {
        if(line.contains("["+ appName +"]")){
            startCollect = true
            continue
        } else if(startCollect) {
            if(!line.allWhitespace && !line.contains('[')){
                hosts.add(line.trim())
            } else {
                break
            }
        } 
    }
    return hosts
}


def hosts = getHostList("client-app", "/absoulte/path/hosts2")
```

The file I am trying to process has the following structure:

```
[Clients]
Client1 ansible_host=192.168.1.2
Client2 ansible_host=192.168.1.3
Client3 ansible_host=192.168.1.4
[Clients:vars]
ansible_ssh_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=basic
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore

[Server]
Server1 ansible_host=192.168.10.2
Server2 ansible_host=192.168.10.3
Server3 ansible_host=192.168.10.4
[Server:vars]
ansible_ssh_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=basic
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore

[Linux]
Linux1 ansible_host=192.168.20.1
....
```

When executing the script I get the following error message

`Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test.readFile() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[file:/absoulte/path/hosts2]] groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test.readFile() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[file:/absoulte/path/hosts2]] at test.getHostList(test.groovy:7) at test.run(test.groovy:2)`

Does any of you have an idea how I can solve the problem or how I can manage to store all hostnames under the groups (the ones in the square brackets) into one variable?

Thanks and Regards

Changed the path. When running the script in Jenkins, its working flawless.

Comment: readFile is a Jenkins pipeline step and not present in plain groovy. However you could define it as a function.

Comment: Additionally, you could format the inventory file as YAML or JSON to utilize native Groovy parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
[Clients]
Client1 ansible_host=192.168.1.2
Client2 ansible_host=192.168.1.3
Client3 ansible_host=192.168.1.4
[Clients:vars]
ansible_ssh_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=basic
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore

[Server]
Server1 ansible_host=192.168.10.2
Server2 ansible_host=192.168.10.3
Server3 ansible_host=192.168.10.4
[Server:vars]
ansible_ssh_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=basic
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore

[Linux]
Linux1 ansible_host=192.168.20.1
```

---

Q: ***"Store all hostnames under the groups into one variable."***

A: There are more options:

1. Ansible automatically creates the dictionary of all groups. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: groups
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  groups:
    Clients:
    - Client1
    - Client2
    - Client3
    Linux:
    - Linux1
    Server:
    - Server1
    - Server2
    - Server3
    all:
    - Client1
    - Client2
    - Client3
    - Server1
    - Server2
    - Server3
    - Linux1
    ungrouped: []
```

All hosts are automatically listed in *groups.all*.

2. Use *ansible-inventory* if you want to parse the inventory on your own. For example, create YAML dictionary

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i hosts --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    Clients:
      hosts:
        Client1:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.2
          ansible_ssh_port: 5985
          ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
          ansible_winrm_transport: basic
        Client2:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.3
          ansible_ssh_port: 5985
          ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
          ansible_winrm_transport: basic
        Client3:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.4
          ansible_ssh_port: 5985
          ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
          ansible_winrm_transport: basic
    Linux:
      hosts:
        Linux1:
          ansible_host: 192.168.20.1
    Server:
      hosts:
        Server1:
          ansible_host: 192.168.10.2
          ansible_ssh_port: 5985
          ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
          ansible_winrm_transport: basic
        Server2:
          ansible_host: 192.168.10.3
          ansible_ssh_port: 5985
          ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
          ansible_winrm_transport: basic
        Server3:
          ansible_host: 192.168.10.4
          ansible_ssh_port: 5985
          ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
          ansible_winrm_transport: basic
    ungrouped: {}
```

The default format of *ansible-inventory* is JSON

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i hosts --list
{
    "Clients": {
        "hosts": [
            "Client1",
            "Client2",
            "Client3"
        ]
    },
    "Linux": {
        "hosts": [
            "Linux1"
        ]
    },
    "Server": {
        "hosts": [
            "Server1",
            "Server2",
            "Server3"
        ]
    },
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "Client1": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.1.2",
                "ansible_ssh_port": 5985,
                "ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation": "ignore",
                "ansible_winrm_transport": "basic"
            },
            "Client2": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.1.3",
                "ansible_ssh_port": 5985,
                "ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation": "ignore",
                "ansible_winrm_transport": "basic"
            },
            "Client3": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.1.4",
                "ansible_ssh_port": 5985,
                "ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation": "ignore",
                "ansible_winrm_transport": "basic"
            },
            "Linux1": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.20.1"
            },
            "Server1": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.10.2",
                "ansible_ssh_port": 5985,
                "ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation": "ignore",
                "ansible_winrm_transport": "basic"
            },
            "Server2": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.10.3",
                "ansible_ssh_port": 5985,
                "ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation": "ignore",
                "ansible_winrm_transport": "basic"
            },
            "Server3": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.10.4",
                "ansible_ssh_port": 5985,
                "ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation": "ignore",
                "ansible_winrm_transport": "basic"
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "Clients",
            "Linux",
            "Server",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }
}
```

You can use *jq* to parse JSON. For example, get all hostnames

```bash
shell> ansible-inventory -i hosts --list | jq '._meta.hostvars | keys[]'
"Client1"
"Client2"
"Client3"
"Linux1"
"Server1"
"Server2"
"Server3"
```